# Share LESS variables between multiple micro-frontends applications

Tags: webpack, less, micro-frontend, single-spa

I'm trying to figured out if it's possible share LESS variables among different React projects. I'm using Single-SPA to build a micro-frontends architecture. My micro-frontends are using some shared components like the [react-microfrontend example](https://github.com/react-microfrontends) does with [react-mf/styleguide](https://github.com/react-microfrontends/styleguide). Beside that, I also need to share some LESS variables (e.g. colors or typography) so I can just define them once into my styleguide project alike and then reference them in every micro-frontends I will define. Is that possible ? If yes, can you suggest to me a way to do that ? I guess the solution is to use webpack but I can't find the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two possible solutions:

**CDN**

```
// index.less file of my new app

@import url(https://your.cdn.url/file.less);
```

Use a CDN to serve the LESS file so it can be imported in every applications we want. After the import statement we can use all the variables the less file contains.

**NPM package**

Publish the LESS file into as an npm package so that file can be imported as a dependency in every application you need (`npm install` or `yarn add`).

I'm using the first approach to start. If someone else will have some different ideas you are welcome!